# Firebase storage files path for web based audio player

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, web-audio-api

I am trying to make a web based audio player and I use firebase storage for keeping audio  files. I got problem with storage  because firebase doesn't provide http link. Can anyone explaine How i use firebase storage download url  or gs path for web based audio player?

Comment: It is possible to generate or get an HTTP link. Please provide some samples of code you have tried, or resources you have referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Storage provides a download URL for your files. You can manually get the download URL by clicking on the file, then opening the `File Location` tab on the right, then clicking on `Download URL`.

[image]

You can get the download URL from your JavaScript with [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url). Or you can get the download URL from Firebase Cloud Functions with [file.getSignedUrl()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.5.x/File#getSignedUrl). Note that `getsignedUrl()` doesn't work until you set the Storage Object Creator role for your appspot service account in your Google Cloud Platform IAM & admin permissions page.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 2 step process. First, you upload the audio file.

Second, use cloud functions `.onCreate` trigger to get, then write the info about the newly added audio file to Firestore (the database). [URL shortening can be automated](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) inside this cloud function.

End state is that you have the audio file stored in Cloud Storage and the info about the audio file stored in Firestore.